# Small output voltage even if transistor is not triggered

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator

I have created following optoisolated NPN transistor switch to run a solenoid valve. The circuit is triggered from the D2 pin of Arduino. When D2 pin goes high, the circuit does switch to correct ~12v output. But when the D2 pin is low, I consistently get small voltage somewhere between 0.3 to 0.6V. What's the reason of this?

The circuit is built with following:

- 4N25 optoisolator
- TIP122
- Arduino powered from PC, whereas switched circuit with 12V power adapter

[image]

Comment: Tip122 is a high gain Darlington so a small leakage current through the opto transistor is enough to turn it on. Try adding a 10k between base and ground to bleed the leakage away.

Comment: @dirac16: I think Arduino and 12V should not have common ground, they have been separated optically by 4N25, to keep Arduino circuit safe from switched circuit. I think that's how it should ideally work. Please correct me if I am wrong (I am not an electronics expert). 
P.S. Also earlier when TIP122 was not optically isolated (Arduino D2 was directly triggering TIP122 base) i was facing same issue. Hence I have feeling that it's not related to ground

Comment: Found the issue, it's due to 1N4007 diode. This circuit is used to drive solenoid valve, hence this diode is important. For test purpose when I removed this diode, problem valished, multimeter shows zero volt when base signal is not present. Now how to solve this diode leakage issue? Do I need to change something in circult or switch to other model of diode?

Comment: Is that measurement between the +/− pins, or to ground?

Comment: It's measurement between +/- signs shown in image